# c++ addition of header files in linux - g++

Tags: c++, linux

All right I am tired looking for question so i guess time to ask now :)
Before I describe the problem, my project works fine on visual 2013 but not suse linux g++ 4.6.2

we are suppose to use a library cio which consist of three files console.h, console.cpp and keys.h . The main program that uses three files is called happy.cpp.

Now on visual studio 2013 all works fine. but when I try to compile on linux, it gives me lots of errors.

Following is a brief code description of the project

```
//console.h
namespace cio {

// Console holds the state of the Console Input Output Facility
//
class Console {
    //some varialbes and functions
    int   getRows() const;
};

extern Console console; // console object - external linkage

} // end namespace cio

===============================================================================
//console.cpp
/* table of platforms */
#define CIO_LINUX       1
#define CIO_MICROSOFT   2
#define CIO_BORLAND     3
#define CIO_UNIX        4

/* auto-select your platform here */
#if   defined __BORLANDC__
    #define CIO_PLATFORM CIO_BORLAND
    #define CIO_LOWER_LEVEL_H_ <conio.h>
#elif defined _MSC_VER
    #define CIO_PLATFORM CIO_MICROSOFT
    #include <windows.h>
    #define CIO_LOWER_LEVEL_H_ <conio.h>
#elif defined __MACH__
    #define CIO_PLATFORM CIO_UNIX
    #define CIO_LOWER_LEVEL_H_ <curses.h>
#elif defined __GNUC__
    #define CIO_PLATFORM CIO_LINUX
    #define CIO_LOWER_LEVEL_H_ <ncurses.h>
#elif !defined __BORLANDC__ && !defined _MSC_VER && !defined __GNUC__ && !defined __MACH__
    #error CONSOLE_PLT is undefined
#endif

extern "C" {
    #include CIO_LOWER_LEVEL_H_
}

#include "console.h"
#include "keys.h"

namespace cio { // continuation of cio namespace

// getRows retrieves the number of rows in the output object
//
int  Console::getRows() const {
    return bufrows;
}

} // end namespace cio
================================================================================
//////happy.cpp
 #include "console.h"
 #include "keys.h"    // for ESCAPE
 using namespace cio;

 int main() {
     int key, rows, columns;

     // get screen dimensions
     rows    = console.getRows();
 }
```

On compiling using "g++ happyface.cpp" command, I get following errors

happyface.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `cio::console'
happyface.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to`cio::Console::getRows() const

I dont know what I am doing wrong here?
I also tried including the paths "g++ -I ~/happy/console.h ~/happy/console.cpp ~/happy/keys.h" and still the same problem.

Comment: That is a linker error, not a compiler error. The `-I` won't help as that is a compiler flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extern Console console; // console object - external linkage
```

Make sure it's actually defined somewhere, e.g. in `console.cpp`. I'm not seeing any definition.

```
g++ -I ~/happy/console.h ~/happy/console.cpp ~/happy/keys.h
```

The `-I` flag should not be necessary. Assuming your directory looks like this:

```
~/happy
 - console.h
 - console.cpp
 - keys.h
 - happyface.cpp
```

You should be able to just do

```
cd ~/happy
g++ console.cpp happyface.cpp -o happyface
./happyface
```

Comment: `extern Console console;` **is** the declaration. What's missing is the **definition**.

Answer (score 0):

You must link every translation unit (aka `.cpp` files) together.

Compile using `g++ happyface.cpp console.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

You declared in console.h your variable console as :

```
extern Console console;
```

but you haven't defined it anywhere.

Add the definition in happy.cpp :

```
namespace cio {
Console console;
}
```

---

Another obvious problem : you are not compiling and linking the console.cpp file. 'For quick and dirty compilation you can do :

```
g++ happyface.cpp console.cpp
```